# pass environment variable values from yaml to json

Tags: json, azure-devops, yaml

I have my build.yaml file where I control the deployment process in the Azure DevOps CI/CD release pipeline. Here I set environment variables which I intend to use in other files along the CI/CD release pipeline.

***build.yaml***

```
  if( "$(env)" -eq "DEVELOPMENT")
  {   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=server]developmentserver" }  
  if( "$(env)" -eq "TEST")
  {   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=server]testserver" }  
  if( "$(env)" -eq "PRODUCTION")
  {   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=server]productionserver" }
```

I would like to use this `${{ variables.server }}` in a template json document which is below.

***template.json***

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "LinkedService_connectionString": {
            "value": "${{ variables.server }}"
        }
    }
}
```

How will I be able to accomplish this?